# How do the Naboo elect a queen?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

The Naboo Queen is elected, uses a decoy, and still uses her real name when in discise.

The fact that she's elected means that the people of Naboo and others that might follow the election know who is elected to be queen.

In order to protect herself, the queen has a number of handmaidens that will occasionally pretend to be the queen as she pretends to be one of them. This helps to protect her against assassination attempts.

However, while pretending to be one of the handmaidens, Padmé uses her real name. Would this not be the name she was elected under? If so, doesn't this make using a disguise useless? If not, how does the election process on Naboo work?

Comment: At least part of your question is answered here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10616/why-did-padme-use-her-real-name?rq=1