# Did the people of Naboo ever find out that Senator Amidala had been secretly married to Anakin and that she had died during childbirth?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I would like to know if the people of Naboo ever found out that Senator Amidala had been secretly married to Anakin and that she had died during childbirth. Is there anything in Star Wars literature that mentions that the people of Naboo eventually found out about all this?

Comment: Jar-Jar Binks and Padme's doppelganger probably knew as they're her best friends and would keep their secret.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143837/20774

Comment: Point of clarification: she was no longer *Queen* Amidala when she wed Anakin and had their children; she was *Senator* Amidala. While still arguably a massively important global role for the planet of Naboo, "Senator" is significantly *less* important, in the command structure, than "Queen", so she probably was able to enjoy far more privacy in her daily life as a Republic Senator vs. when she was the supreme ruler of the planet.

Comment: @TylerH, that's a good point that you make about her being a Senator when she gave birth to her children. I will make this title change in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the novelisation of Revenge of the Sith, there's a scene that covers some of this.

> Around a conference table on *Tantive IV*, Bail Organa, Obi-Wan Kenobi
> and Yoda met to decide the fate of the galaxy. "To Naboo, send her
> body ... Pregnant, she must still appear"

So the three of them certainly covered up that she'd had her children.

Comment: Yeah, it would've been a bit counterproductive to have a whole planet know that she had given birth. Which brings up the question, aside from the Jedi, who else knew that it was Anakin's children being carried by Padme?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the OP is particularly asking about if the people of Naboo know the secret, but none of Yoda, Kenobi and Organa are citizens of that planet. -1

Comment: @Hans Well it answers the second clause, they didn't, because she was buried looking pregnant (i.e. her cause of death wasn't childbirth).

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Ok, -1/2 then!